# Mount/Unmount filesystem from macOS kernel extension

Tags: macos, filesystems, kernel-extension, xnu

`hdiutil` can attach and detach a DMG file containing HFS+ partition, into selected mount-point. However, it uses the private API of `DiskImages.framework`. My aim is to make this task fully programmatic, so I look for alternative in the kernel drivers realm.

while delving into the KPI represented by `<sys/mount.h>` I found useful method for unmount filesystem according to its matching fsid:

```
int vfs_unmountbyfsid(fsid_t *fsid, int flags, vfs_context_t ctx)
```

However, do we have the opposite operation for mount ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a public KPI for initiating a mount, and I'm not even aware of a function in `com.apple.kpi.private`. In user space however, there's a lot more than DiskImages.framework at your disposal: there's the `DiskArbitration.framework`, and of course the POSIX syscall of `mount(2)`.

I think you might be conflating 2 concepts here, which are actually entirely separate:

1. Opening disk images and creating a virtual block device for accessing their contents
2. Mounting a file system on a block device.

Disk image support is not an intrinsic part of the xnu kernel. They're implemented in the `IOHDIXController` object (code for this is in a kext), which you'll find attached to `IOResources` in the IORegistry. When the user double-clicks a .dmg file or similar, the `diskimages-helper` daemon opens & parses it and instructs the IOHDIXController to create a new `IODiskImageBlockStorageDeviceOutKernel` instance (an `IOBlockStorageDevice` subclass). This appears to the OS like a physical block device, and the usual stack of `IOBlockStorageDriver` -> `IOMedia` -> `IOPartitionScheme` -> `IOMedia` -> `IOMediaBSDClient` objects configures itself on top of it. This then causes device discovery events to fire in `diskarbitrationd`, which moves on to the second part of the process: calling `mount(2)` on the newly discovered `IOMedia` objects' `/dev/diskXsY` node(s) as appropriate.

The HDIX subsystem is not open as far as I'm aware. So if you want to implement your own disk image format, you'll need to recreate something similar to Apple's `diskimage-helper` and `IOHDIXController.kext`. You can probably get away with implementing it entirely in-kernel if you prefer, although it's probably not a great idea.

The second part, mounting, is done by diskarbitrationd automatically if you are using the IOStorage stack, but you can influence it via a disk arbitration dissenter. See DiskArbitration.framework for details. But this also lets you influence mounting of disk images handled by `diskimages-helper`, so if you are using an image format supported by it, you won't need to write your own and can simply intercept the mounting and do whatever it is you want to do yourself.

You can probably also bypass the IOStorage stack entirely and only create the BSD dev node in your kext. In that case, diskarbitrationd shouldn't notice it, and you will need to call `mount()` explicitly from your daemon.

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Hi, the reason i wish that my process to be in charge of attaching the dmg file into mounpoint process, is that I've got kauth module that filter out other processes when accessing the image file (.dmg), and avoid whitelisting apple tools (such as hfs_mount and hdiutil). notice that the dmg is already hfs+ formatted, i just need to attach it to some mountpoint so i can access its contents. I tried to for diskarbitration, DADiskMount but it require device name and not image file.

Comment: by the way, I've tried to use `mount(2)`, but it requires device file according to `struct hfs_mount_args`. the only thing I lack in order to make the mount process fully programmatically, is to imitate the `hdiutil attach` that attaches the image file (dmg) to device file. any idea how this can be done ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 I think you're confusing mounting with opening disk images. These are 2 separate processes. I've updated my answer to explain exactly how it works.